# Computing expectation of a stochastic integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I need to compute the expectation

> $$E\left[\int_0^tu \, dB_u  \int_0^s u \, dB_u \right].$$

Being that is my first question, how can I initialize MathJax if I have it on my hard drive.

Comment: MathJax is not something that you need to "initialize"... nor is it something that you need to install on your hard drive.  It is simply a script (written in Javascript) that is installed on MSE's servers; everything should work automatically.

Comment: To rephrase my question, how can I make the formulas i write look better. I usually write them in Microsoft Word. Can I copy them from there and put them between dollar signs?

Comment: MathJax uses a different format from MS Word; it's more like LaTeX.  So you probably will not be able to paste from Word.  But see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a introduction to MathJax.

Comment: Some other tips: The `<script>` line you added to your post is unnecessary.  Next, people don't usually start their posts with "Hello"; you can mouseover questions on the front page to see the first part of the question, so it's better if it says something substantive.  Finally, for questions that look like the statement of a homework problem, people expect you to include some background on what you know and what you have tried; see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No idea about MathJax but your integral is $E[M_tM_s]$ where $M_t=\int\limits_0^tu \, \mathrm dB_u$. The process $(M_r)_{r\geqslant0}$ is a square-integrable martingale with $M_0=0$ hence, for every $t\geqslant s$, $E[M_tM_s]=E[M_s^2]=E[\langle M\rangle_s]$. 
Now, $\langle M\rangle_s=\int\limits_0^su^2 \, \mathrm d\langle B\rangle_u$ hence $\langle M\rangle_s$ is $____$ and...

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. So it's $s^3/3$.And $E[sB_s ∫_0^t〖u dB_u 〗]$ is $s^3/2$ or I'm doing something wrong.